# Desktop PC personal

Tags: windows-7

Can Ddr3 Corsair  1600 MHz ram will support to my motherboard my motherboard Name ZEB H61 Zebronics motherboard H 61 can both ram run in my motherboard and my processor is i3 and 1TB hardisk
and it also mention in my motherboard Box that support 
H61 motherboard 1066/1333 & 1600

So I’m purchasing ram so that before buying i ask u about my Query 
Below ram details :- 
Corsair Vengeance 4Gb 240 Ddr3 Sd Ram 1600MHz
Corsair Vengeance 8 Gb Ddr3 Sd Ram 1600Mhz 
 please confirm me

Answer (score 0):

You can find the specifications of your motherboard here:

https://zebronics.com/products/motherboards/zeb-h61-socket-1155

https://www.pc-specs.com/mobo/Zebronics/Zebronics_ZEB-H61/2319

> Memory support
>
> 2  DDR3 dual-channel slots, Support DDR3 1066/1333/1600MHz memory

Yes, this should support Corsair 8GB DDR3 1600 MHz RAM. If you can tell us the exact model, we can verify it precisely. Since the motherboard only has 2 memory slots, it will have to be 2 x 4GB and not 4 x 2GB. Also, the 2nd link mentions that 8GB is the maximum amount of RAM supported.